# How to create struct values access code from text fields

Tags: go, struct

Go program will ingest streaming telemetry in JSON format, and will unmarshall to a defined struct (nested structs)

```
type Struct1 struct {
    Inner1 Struct2 `json:"struct2,omitempty"`
    Inner2 Struct3 `json:"struct3,omitempty"`
}
type Struct2 struct {
    Value1 string `json:"value1,omitempty"`
    Value2 string `json:"value2,omitempty"`
}
type Struct3 struct {
    Value1 string `json:"value1,omitempty"`
    Value2 string `json:"value2,omitempty"`
}
```

We will know at runtime (not compile) what values are required from the struct.
eg: value1 and value2 in struct2;

```
"path":  {"struct1","struct2"},
"value": {"value1", "value2"},
```

We have to extract these values.

We can (similar to python code) create a tree structure of string matching case-switch, and start iterating through the nested structs and values, until we get a string match for the values we want. This would have to be performed on every message received.

But it would be better, more efficient, if we were able to leverage the static properties of go. We know struct values we want and should be able to access the values direct.
Have being trying to think how to translate a list of text "struct1" "struct2" "value1" into a code format of:

```
v := s.Inner1.Value1
```

and then use in the code.
During initialisation the program can translate the value requirements, into struct access code.

Comment: There's no question mark in your "question".

Comment: Depending on how "manageable" the set of all possible paths is, you could initialize a `map[string]func(RootType) string` where the map's key would be the full path, e.g. `"struct1.struct2.value1"` and the corresponding value would be a function returning the desired target value, e.g. `func(s Struct1) string { return s.Inner1.Value1 }`.

Comment: If the set of all possible paths is too big and you don't feel like managing it, then you can write code that generates the map for you, however if that option is also undesirable, then use reflection, although then the goal to _"leverage the static properties of go"_ goes out the window.

Comment: No way around reflection. Package [jsoniter](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/json-iterator/go) provides something like what you want. `jsoniter.Wrap(yourStruct).Get("struct1","struct2")`

Comment: @mkopriva thanks for your pointers (no pun intended)
I will create a method in parallel with each struct, to return the values.
`func (s *Struct2) getValue(key string) interface{} {
 value := make(map[string]interface{})
 value["value1"] = s.Value1
 value["value2"] = s.Value2
 str1 := value[key]
 return str1
}`
And pull the required value from each message. It is not iterating across structs, but it is doubling the size of the code.
And I will most likly get python to automate generating the methods, as there is a lot, and they are nested.